# compiler giving generic error in Collectors toMap

Tags: java, dictionary, generics, arraylist, java-stream

I was writing one simple expression wherein I have to collect `Map` of `String` vs the list of indexes from an array. To do that I am trying to use

```
 Collectors.toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction).
```

Gist of it is as follow.

```
    Map<String, List<Integer>> sortedStringToIndex = IntStream.range(0, strs.length)
 .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String,Integer>(sortString(strs[i]),i))
 .collect(Collectors.toMap((Map.Entry<String,Integer> pair) -> pair.getKey(),
            (Map.Entry<String,Integer> pair) -> {
        List<Integer> val = new ArrayList<>(){{add(pair.getValue());}};
        return val;
        }, (List<Integer> index1, List<Integer> index2) ->  index1.addAll(index2)));
```

But It gives me following error.

> method java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator) is not applicable
>         (inference variable U has incompatible bounds
>           equality constraints: java.util.List
>           lower bounds: java.lang.Boolean,java.util.List)

Can someone please explain the compiler error and how to fix this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-int-java.util.Collection-). It's because `List#addAll` produces `boolean`, it cannot be used as downstream function. You can use streams:

```
Stream.concat(index1.stream(), index2.stream())
                         .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Or using apache commons collections:

```
ListUtils.union(index1, index2)
```

Comment: Ohhh yes My bad.. I was confused with compiler message. And was under the impression addAll return new List. Thank you very much

Comment: Since all lists are freshly created `ArrayList`s here, it would also be correct to use `(list1, list2) -> { list1.addAll(list2); return list1; }` as merge function.

Answer (score 0):

Or like this if you want to follow your code:

```
 (index1, index2) -> {
                        index1.addAll(index2);
                        return index1;
                    }
```

complete version:

```
 Map<String, List<Integer>> sortedStringToIndex = IntStream.range(0, strs.length)
            .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(sortString(strs[i]), i))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                              AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                              pair -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(pair.getValue())),
                              (l1, l2) -> {l1.addAll(l2);return l1; }
                           )
                   );
```

Comment: Collectios.singletonList give immutable list. and further when you will do addAll on it. Then it will give UnsupportedOperation exception. Java's tribute to Open closed principle.